# Какой знак нужен перед "шутит"?

Tags: пунктуация

*...что поди пойми его шутит он или говорит серьезно.*

Comment: Лучше всего поставить запятую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*..что **поди пойми его** ― шутит он или говорит серьезно.*

Между предложениями изъяснительное значение, в этом случае можно использовать **запятую, двоеточие, тире**.

В данном случае лучше поставить **тире**, обозначив увеличенную **паузу.** Это связано с тем, что в устойчивом выражении ***поди пойми его*** используется местоимение ***его***, то есть нет прямого контакта речевого глагола и изъяснительного предложения.

Примеры:

Случились и случились… **поди пойми ее** ― хотела она этих детей или вздохнула с облегчением… [Дина Рубина. На солнечной стороне улицы (1980-2006)]

**Поди пойми**, лавочник он или начальник, если там человек пятьсот, а то и тыщи собрались. [Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема (Книга 1) (1989)]

То же самое и с преступлениями. **Поди пойми**: законно это теперь, незаконно? Я ж не специалист… [Евгений Лукин. Клопики (2013)]